# Doubt about SIGINT and SIG_IGN

Tags: package-management

I am undergoing a course on Operating System and in that as the OS used is Linux we were taught with a program using `SIGINT` and `SIG_IGN`.

When I tried to program the code taught in my PC compiler indicates an error message and both of them can't be found.

How to install a package to install these macros? Or is there anything different I should do to make them work? I use Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: @darent, your [approvement](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/245255) was wrong. `SIG_INT` is a mistake.

Comment: @SylvainPineau, your too

Comment: The Ubuntu version is important here, it just doesn't need to be in the tags necessarily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use both signals you need to include `signal.h`, like this example taken from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_signal_handling) related to C signals:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void catch_function(int signo) {
    puts("Interactive attention signal caught.");
}

int main(void) {
    if (signal(SIGINT, catch_function) == SIG_ERR) {
        fputs("An error occurred while setting a signal handler.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("Raising the interactive attention signal.");
    if (raise(SIGINT) != 0) {
        fputs("Error raising the signal.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    puts("Exiting.");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good answer. I think so about your question. In additional first you  must execute a command like that "apt-get install build-essential"